# Is there any way to get a "clean" CDC log from Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I've been reading up on Postgres logical replication, and I noticed something a little bit disturbing.  [In the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html), it mentions that the logged messages it provides include transaction messages such as begin, commit, *and rollback!*

This strikes me as a bit pointless.  If I'm trying to run Change Data Capture, I couldn't care less about transactions, particularly ones that get rolled back.  By definition that is not *change data,* because it didn't end up changing anything.

Is there any way to get a clean CDC stream from Postgres, that will tell me about changes to the database and ignore any transactions that were rolled back?

Comment: as there can go millions things wrong, the strategy to send a transaction with a defined outcoume comit or rollback, seems to be a good idea, as the transaction can be repeated, if it fails

Comment: @nbk I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what that has to do with CDC?

Comment: you linked the package that will be send to the replicate server and you thing that the information is to big, for some reason, besides rewriting it and replacing it with your own functions, my point still stand, you send a package over the communication network and there can be lossos, which would result in in an error, so the transaction(replication) failed and the replicated server has to rollback, so no unnecessary information is send

Comment: @nbk I'm not talking about the use of transactions within the replication process itself; I'm talking about the WAL capturing transactions, *including failed ones that are utterly irrelevant,* as part of the source stream of data to be replicated.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-streaming.html) says:

> The basic output plugin callbacks (e.g., `begin_cb`, `change_cb`, `commit_cb` and `message_cb`) are only invoked when the transaction actually commits. The changes are still decoded from the transaction log, but are only passed to the output plugin at commit (and discarded if the transaction aborts).
>
> This means that while the decoding happens incrementally, and may spill to disk to keep memory usage under control, all the decoded changes have to be transmitted when the transaction finally commits (or more precisely, when the commit is decoded from the transaction log). Depending on the size of the transaction and network bandwidth, the transfer time may significantly increase the apply lag.
>
> To reduce the apply lag caused by large transactions, an output plugin may provide additional callback to support incremental streaming of in-progress transactions. There are multiple required streaming callbacks (`stream_start_cb`, `stream_stop_cb`, `stream_abort_cb`, `stream_commit_cb` and `stream_change_cb`) and two optional callbacks (`stream_message_cb` and `stream_truncate_cb`). Also, if streaming of two-phase commands is to be supported, then additional callbacks must be provided. (See [Section 49.10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-two-phase-commits.html) for details).

So the behavior depends on the logical decoding plugin you are using. With the basic functionality, you will never see uncommitted changes. But beware: long running transactions can and will break performance in this case.

If you are using `pgoutput`, [`START_REPLICATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-replication.html#PROTOCOL-REPLICATION-START-REPLICATION-SLOT-LOGICALhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-replication.html#PROTOCOL-REPLICATION-START-REPLICATION-SLOT-LOGICAL) allows you to specify the option `streaming on` to stream in-progress transaction. If you don't specify that (or set it to `off`), you'll never see uncommitted data.